# Sixth root of $-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

We know that $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+ \frac{i}{2} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{6})+i \sin (\frac{\pi}{6})=e^\frac{i \pi}{6}$. Therefore we have $(e^\frac{i \pi}{6})^6 =e^{i\pi}= \cos(\pi)+i \sin (\pi)=-1$. (please correct me if this calculation is wrong)

Therefore $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+ \frac{i}{2}$ is one complex sixth root of $-1$.

However when I manually computed $(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+ \frac{i}{2})^6$ by computing its square $3$ times I end up having the expression $\frac{1+ \sqrt3.i}{2}$.

why are these two expressions are not matching?

I have one further question : $(1)$ If we have  $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+ \frac{i}{2}$ is a complex $6$ th root of $-1$, then can explicitly find other $6$th root of $-1$ distinct from the previous one?

Any remark from anyone is welcome.

Comment: The square of the square of the square is the eighth power

Comment: If $z^{6}=-1$ the $(\overline z)^{6}$ is also $-1$.

Comment: @Henry, I see the mistake now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your additional question, let us call the complex sixth-root you've found $ \ s_0 \ = \ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ + \ \frac12·i \ \ , \ $ which is a solution to the polynomial equation $ \ z^6 + 1 \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  We *could* use the factorizations for a "difference of two squares" or "two cubes" to produce $ \ ( \ [z^3]^2 - [i]^2 \ ) \ = \ (z^3 - i)·(z^3 + i) \ = \ 0 \ $ or $ \ ( \ [z^2]^3 + 1^3 \ ) \ = \ (z^2 + 1)·(z^4 - z^2 + 1) \ = \ 0 \ $ in order to solve for the other sixth-roots.  But it is quicker to apply what we know about real-coefficient polynomials and the symmetries (where these are present) among their zeroes.

Because $ \ z^6 + 1 \ $ is an even function, we know that $ \ -s_0 \ = \ -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ - \ \frac12·i \  $ must also be one on its zeroes; this is $ \ cis  \left( \frac{ \pi}{6} + \pi \right) \ = \  cis  \left( \frac{ 7 \pi}{6}  \right) \ = \ s_0^7 \ \ . \  $  As the polynomial in question has real coefficients, we then also have
$$ \overline{s_0} \ = \ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ - \ \frac12·i \ \ = \ \ cis  \left( -\frac{ \pi}{6} \right) \ \ = \ \ cis  \left( \frac{ 11 \pi}{6} \right) \ \ = \ \ s_0^{11}  \ \ \ \text{and} $$
$$ \overline{-s_0} \ = \ -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ + \ \frac12·i \ \ = \ \ cis  \left( -\frac{7 \pi}{6} \right) \ \ = \ \ cis  \left( \frac{ 5 \pi}{6} \right) \ \ = \ \ s_0^5 $$

as sixth-roots of $ \ -1 \ \ . \ $  From the factorizations above, we can use $ \ z^2 \ = \ -1 \ $ or $ \ z^3 \ = \ i \ , \ z^3 \ = \ -i \ $ to establish that $ \ i \ =  \ cis  \left(  \frac{ \pi}{2} \right) \  =  \ cis  \left( \frac{ 3 \pi}{6} \right) \  =  \ s_0^3 \ $ and $ \ -i \ =  \ cis  \left(  \frac{3 \pi}{2} \right) \  =  \ cis  \left( \frac{ 9 \pi}{6} \right) \  =  \ s_0^9 \ $ are also sixth-roots of $ \ -1 \ \ . \ $

This accounts for the expected six complex zeroes of the sixth-degree polynomial $ \ z^6 + 1 \ \ . \ $  The formula from DeMoivre's Theorem tells us that these zeroes are
$$ s_k \ \ = \ \ cis \left( \ \frac{\pi \ + \ 2k \pi}{6} \ \right) \ \ , \ \ k \ = \ 0 \ , \ 1 \ , \ \ldots \ , \ 5 \ \ , \ $$

so we may catalogue the sixth-roots of $ \ -1 \ $ as $$ \ s_0 \ \ , \ \ s_1 \ = \ s_0^3 \ = \ i \ \ , \ \ s_2 \ = \ s_0^5 \ = \ \overline{-s_0} \ \ ,  $$ $$ s_3 \ = \ s_0^7 \ = \ -s_0 \ \ , \ \ s_4 \ = \ s_0^9 \ = \ -i \ \ , \ \ s_5 \ = \ s_0^{11} \ = \ \overline{s_0} \ \ .  $$